# How can I use CSS to align this menu with the rest of the content of my website?

Tags: css

I have a menu that I just can't seem to get in the proper position. It seems to float:left.  But I don't see any place in my CSS where I'm floating anything left.

I'm okay with firebug, but not a guru.  Does anybody know how I can get this to properly align with the rest of the content of the website?

I don't know if I should be using `float:`, or `text-align`, or whatever CSS function.  I also don't know if I should be using `#` or `.` before the ID or class.

So it looks like this:

[image]

If it helps, **[the site is here](http://www.occupyhln.org)**.  Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer.

**EDIT:**

The following is the CSS from the menu I'm using, which, again, looks like the picture on the latest version of FF on all of my computers:

```
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item {font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul, #dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul, #dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul.menu {background: #8998a8 url(skins/images/bg_grey.png) repeat-x 0 -80px; width: 100%; height: 40px; border-right: 1px solid #8B949F; border-left: 1px solid #8B949F; position: relative;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a {float: left; display: block; color: #fff; padding: 12px 38px 12px 25px; background: url(skins/images/bg_grey.png) repeat-x 100% 0; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; text-decoration: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a.dc-mega {position: relative;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a .dc-mega-icon {display: block; position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 15px; width: 8px; height: 6px; background: url(skins/images/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li.mega-hover a, #dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li a:hover {background-position: 100% -40px; color: #000; text-shadow: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li.mega-hover a .dc-mega-icon {background-position: 0 100%;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container {position: absolute; background: url(skins/images/bg_sub_left.png) no-repeat 0 100%; padding-left: 20px; margin-left: -3px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub {background: url(skins/images/bg_sub.png) no-repeat 100% 100%; padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 10px 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul.full-width li .sub-container.mega .sub {margin-right: -2px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub .row {width: 100%; overflow: hidden; clear: both;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li {list-style: none; float: none; width: 170px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr {margin: 0 10px 10px 0; float: left;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr.last {margin-right: 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub a {background: none; border: none; text-shadow: none; color: #111; padding: 7px 10px; display: block; float: none; text-decoration: none; font-size: 0.9em;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a {padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px; margin-bottom: 5px; background: #8A98A9 url(skins/images/bg_mega_hdr.png) no-repeat 0 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a:hover {color: #000; text-shadow: none;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul .sub li.mega-hdr li a {padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px; background: url(skins/images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 5px 8px; font-weight: normal;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul .sub li.mega-hdr li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(skins/images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 5px 8px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul .sub ul li {padding-right: 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega li {padding: 0; width: 190px; margin: 0;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega li a {padding: 7px 5px 7px 22px; background: url(skins/images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(skins/images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
```

**SOLVED:**

It was a #wrap function error ... dealing with Catalyst.  Thanks for all those who tried to help.

Comment: Your website does not look like the picture...

Comment: @Zenith It may be a browser-specific issue. What browser did you take that screenshot from Jason?

Comment: @eggy I just tried Chrome and Firefox, most recent versions. He mentions Firebug so he's using Firefox I guess

Comment: Is that a new menu? Cause current menu is aligned here.

Comment: It doesn't look like the picture in my up-to-date version of Chrome, or even IE9.

Comment: Is this misalignment on the live site? Because there seems to be no issue/we cannot recreate it.

Comment: Eggy, I used FF for the screenshot, but it looks the same to me in Chrome and IE10 ....   Francisco, I used a Wordpress plugin to replace the theme's regular menu with this menu.  Eggy, I'm not sure ... other than to say it's a plugin for WordPress.  So I created a custom widget area where I placed this WordPress menu plugin. Thanks for the comments everyone!

Comment: @JasonWeber To me it looks like this - http://postimg.org/image/yv5vfpjy7/ in all major browsers

Comment: Zenith, you're correct.  I just checked Chrome and IE 10 again, and that's really confusing to me.  I guess I really have to go back to the drawing board.  But in the latest FF, it looks like what I posted on my end.  Thanks for informing me and sharing the screenshot!

Comment: Im using latest FF and it is fine. Maybe thats a cached version? Try cleaning cache and refresh page.

Comment: I've checked on 3 desktops and my laptop, and it looks like what the pic looks like in FF, but not in Chrome or IE.

Comment: All these downvotes are cool, though ... they don't bother me at all.  I'm humored by most of 'em. hehe

Comment: I think the downvotes are because of the lack of information and clarity on the question. Some code would be good and that is probably a simple problem that we hope it will be solved.
What version of FF are you using? You say its the last one but im using that and it's good, give me a number please. Menu -> options -> About.
Also the CSS styles on the pic dont match the css on the link.

Comment: PS: Please give us some html code of that part of the page and the respective css.

Comment: Francisco, it's a Catalyst WordPress site, so it's tough to find their coding, and although it's not obfuscated, it's difficult to ascertain.  But I'll try!

Comment: css without the html is nothing. Please provide some relevant html. 
If you dont have it load the page and copy paste relevant part of the source code.

Comment: Thanks Francisco.  I figured it out -- at least it works on my Firefox on all my puters, but not Chrome or IE -- yet.  I'll get it to work, though.  It was a Catalyst-related widget area css issue dealing with the #wrap.

Comment: What i dont understand is why it was working here xD
But nevermind, glad you got it running.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to align centered horizontal you need to set margin: 0px auto;

@edit: With no float btw.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from your picture so I'll take a stab in the dark.

Give the #navbar-1-wrap (which I presume is your menu bar) the following properties in your CSS file. If any of these already exist for it, delete and use these new ones.

```
width: 920px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Ok. That completes my stab in the dark.

Comment: Stab in the dark? That is a stab blind-folded while tied to an anchor 5km deep in the ocean

Comment: That is not a stab in the dark, that is a copy of my previous answer. 
Clap

Comment: @Zenith - totally agreed but it is the only kind of stab the OP has allowed us so far!

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso This answer arrived only a minute after yours - perfectly possible it wasn't seen before being posted.

Comment: Sorry, Fran. Didn't see your answer. There's no need to get your jimmies rustled. Though for margin auto to work the width of the div needs to be set explicitly.

Comment: @sscirrus, i guess my answer was already there, the user just don't cared about reading. Like most of them do.

Comment: @user1183550 its fine, and you're right about width, but looking at the picture it seems like it is defined so i didn't said that. But it's right. Just read the answers next time.

Comment: Thanks user118.  I'll give that a go, but I replaced my navbar1 with a WordPress menu plugin, so I have no navbar1 or navbar2 ... I just have this custom widget area that I created and that's where I placed this menu.  Thanks for taking the time to take a stab in the dark!